# New Instagram API, how to get post by tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, instagram, instagram-api

Since 1st June 2016 Instagram has tightened its API, is not possible anymore to create an app whose only goal is to retrieve the most recent media by tag (I need to do it for a website).

I'm referring to this endpoint in particular:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent
```

Somewhere in the docs they say you can use a third part service (which should do "content discovery") to obtain the same result.

Do you know any service like this? Or any workaround to get it working again?

Comment: I'm with the same problem, Do you get it working?

Comment: My issue was that I need to get recent media from my user. Solved by using this URL "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN&count=6"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any services like that, but while looking for the same workaround I've stumbled upon a PHP library, that should do the job

https://github.com/Bolandish/Instagram-Grabber

Should be fairly easy to use, although I'm not sure it's 100% legal to use Instagram this way.